# Can multiple bearer token supported in Authorization header

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, jax-rs, bearer-token, jwt

In JAVA based application, we are receiving JWT token through `Authoriztion` HttpHeader. As I know HttpHeader can contains multiple value against one Header Key.

So here want to know whether the `Authoriztion` http header can also contains multiple `bearer` token value in same header ? I know `Authorization` header can contains multiple token of different type like Basic, Bearer etc.

**But can it also contains multiple same type of token as value ?**

```
as example: (Whether it is valid or not)
"Authorization" : "Bearer XXXXXX1, Bearer XXXXX2"
```

**Any RFC reference will be helpful.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** It's possible and some server could be handling it but it's not RFC valid.

**Long answer:**

This can be valid, as defined in [RFC7230, section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2), Field Order:

> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to the combined field value in order, separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value; a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when forwarding a message.

Each "Bearer XXXX" should be considered as separate field-value.

So some servers may be able to handle it ...

... But the "Authorization" RFC ([RFC7235, Appendix C](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#appendix-C)) adds more rules specificaly for the Authorization header

> Authorization = credentials

> credentials = auth-scheme [ 1*SP ( token68 / [ ( "," / auth-param )
> *( OWS "," [ OWS auth-param ] ) ] ) ]

> auth-param = token BWS "=" BWS ( token / quoted-string )

So it seems you shouldn't be able to contains multiple token of different type like Basic, Bearer etc. As it accept only one auth-scheme

The RFC for Bearer ([RFC6750 section2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1)) is even more simple

> b64token    = 1*( ALPHA / DIGIT /
> "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / "+" / "/" ) *"="

> credentials = "Bearer" 1*SP b64token

So it can contain multiple values of the same or different scheme, some server will accept it because it's a valid header,but it will not be RFC valid because the Authorization header is more restrictive.